# Add event to personal calendar for SPO without using Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, designer-workflow, calendar

We need a logic to add event to M365 users' personal calendar according to a company calendar (saved in SPO). We didn't have Power Automate plan so it is not an option.

Could we use SPD2013 workflow? Could we use PowerShell for SPO?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell might be a better choice since SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow needs a manual trigger or to be built on a specific object.

If the personal calendar is saved in a SharePoint list, here is a sample script you can use to add new events:

```
#Variables
$SiteURL = "<SiteURL>"
$CalendarName = "Calendar"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Add Event to Calendar
Add-PnPListItem -List $CalendarName -Values @{
    "Title" = "Team Meeting";
    "Description"= "Monthly Team Meeting";
    "Location"= "Ballroom";
    "EventDate" = [datetime]"11/04/2020 8AM";
    "EndDate"=[datetime]"11/04/2020 6PM";
}
```

Reference: [SharePoint Online: Add Calendar Item using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/06/sharepoint-online-add-calendar-event-using-powershell.html)

---

UPDATE:

If the events are not in SharePoint list, then that is out of SharePoint’s scope. You will need to use **Exchange Online PowerShell** instead.

Please see the reference here:
[Use mail flow rules to automatically add meetings to calendars in Exchange Online.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/use-rules-to-add-meetings)

Comment: "Personal calendar" means the calendar for each user's outlook online calendar. Is it possible?

Comment: @MarkL Please see the updated answer.